# Is for-yield-getOrElse paradigmatic Scala or is there a better way?

Tags: scala

Basically I want to extract a bunch of Options a, b, etc.  Is this the best way to do this in Scala?  It looks kind of confusing to me to have the for-yield in parenthesis.

```
(for {
  a <- a
  b <- b
  c <- c
  ...
} yield {
  ...
}) getOrElse {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like you won't get better than this with *core* scala, but possibly you can [give a try for scalaz](http://www.casualmiracles.com/2012/01/16/a-small-example-of-applicative-functors-with-scalaz/)?

Comment: The scalaz example doesn't really deal with this scenario but instead with 3 independent Options; here the question is about nested Options; am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with a for-comprehension wrapped in parens, it is an expression like any other. I do it all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `map` and `flatMap` instead. Assume you have the following class hierarchy:

```
case class C(x: Int)
case class B(c: Option[C])
case class A(b: Option[B])

val a = Some(A(Some(B(Some(C(42))))))
```

In order to extract `42` you can say:

```
a.flatMap(_.b).flatMap(_.c).map(_.x).getOrElse(-1)
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
for(
  a <- a
  b <- a.b
  c <- b.c)
      yield c.x
```

except that it returns `Some(42)`. In fact `for` comprehension is actually translated into a sequence of `map`/`flatMap` calls.

Comment: so there will be a chain of flatMaps/maps? (Garret wrote `...` so I guess there will be more than two options)

Comment: What about for c, d, etc?  And which is paradigmatic, if there is such a thing in Scala?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I reformulated my example to clearly indicate how chaining is implemented.

Comment: @GarrettHall: check out my new example. If you have several unrelated `Option[]` types, just extract them separately, one after another.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz frankly, my eyes are bleeding, for comprehension looks much better

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I have to agree, after all for comprehension were invented to avoid chained `map`/`flatMap`/`filter`/`foreach` if they don't look well. It's a matter of choosing best tool in particular case.